# How can I compare sums of two tables in a single query?

Tags: mysql

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fae8a/6

I've got three tables -- orders, order_line_items, order_payments.

I can aggregate the totals and payments of the orders using a select statement, but I can't seem to figure out the right syntax to return only orders that have 'payments' that add up to less than 'total' (orders not paid in full).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `HAVING` clause to filter results by aggregate functions,you also need to use `COALESCE()` to filter out the null

```
select 
    `orders`.`id`, 
    `order_payments`.`order_id`, 
    `order_payments`.`amount`, 
    `order_line_items`.`order_id`, 
    `order_line_items`.`price_each`, 
    `order_line_items`.`quantity`,
    COALESCE(SUM(`order_line_items`.`price_each` * `order_line_items`.`quantity`),0) as `order_total`,
    COALESCE(SUM(`order_payments`.`amount`),0) as `payments`
from 
    `orders` 
left join 
    `order_payments` on `order_payments`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id` 
left join 
    `order_line_items` on `order_line_items`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id`
group by 
    `orders`.`id`
HAVING   `payments` < `order_total`
```

### [Updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fae8a/30)

**EDIT from comments**

Another way to rewrite your query is using subquery your previous query is giving you the Cartesian product

```
select 
    `o`.`id`,
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(`price_each` * `quantity`),0) FROM `order_line_items` WHERE order_id =`o`.`id` ) as `order_total`,
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(`amount`),0) FROM `order_payments` WHERE order_id =`o`.`id`) as `payments`
from 
    `orders` o
HAVING   `payments` < `order_total`
```

### [**Without Having Clause**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a80acf/14)

### [**With Having Clause**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a80acf/17)

Comment: I don't think we're quite there -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fae8a/32 -- my query gets no results, when it should get two -- it should return order #1 and order #2, which have no payments entered.  Order 3 has 1 payment for the full amount. Edit -- didn't see the updated fiddle with the coaleesce().  Thanks!

Comment: @user686198 see my updated answer and [**updated fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fae8a/30)

Comment: Not quite working properly yet -- see this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a80acf/3 -- the order total and payments are now being multiplied somehow.  Look at order 2.  The total should be $80, but it shows $320.  The Payments should be $40, but it shows $80.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use where on an sum() use having instead.